# Sending default role in nodeJS application

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

StackOverflow community!

I've been working on a project which involves roles. Now I made one admin and one moderator thru postman and it's saved into my DB.

Now when user signs up, I want to send default role of "user" to my DB, which the admin can update later on (if he wants).

Old code where I would send role type:

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  // Save User to Database
  console.log("Processing func -> SignUp");
  
  User.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)
  }).then(user => {
    Role.findAll({
      where: {
      name: {
        [Op.or]: req.body.roles
      }
      }
    }).then(roles => {
      user.setRoles(roles).then(() => {
        res.send("User registered successfully!");
            });
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send("Fail! Error -> " + err);
  })
}
```

And postman request looked like:

```
{
    "name": "Examp",
    "username": "example",
    "email": "gmail@gmail.com",
    "roles": ["admin"],
    "password": "12345"
}
```

And this worked perfectly. I only now want to send postman request without "roles" part. I know that trick is somewhere at `Role.finndAll` part but I can't figure it out (well i think it's there lol). I've tried to replace `[Op.or]: req.body.roles` with `roles: ["user"]` But It didn't worked.

I would really appreciate help!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `where: {
      name: "user"
      }`?

Comment: @Anatoly works like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just try this:

```js
where: { 
  name: "user"
}
```

It's equal to `name="user"` if you write it in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is by @Anatoly
Correction needed is

```
where: {       name: "user"       }
```